# Trying to transfer csv file from EC2 to PostgreSQL RDS; get FATAL psql init file error

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, file-transfer, amazon-rds

I'm fairly new to AWS in general. I'm currently trying to replicate work by another group and therefore am attempting to mimic their setup. I've established an EC2 instance (Amazon Linux AMI) and a PostgreSQL 9.3.5 RDS instance. I've uploaded a 4 GB csv file to EC2 and would like to copy it to a table in my RDS db. I used the following code within the EC2 shell (following 2nd set of instructions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Procedural.Importing.html)):

```
psql -h XX.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com -U username -d DBname -p 5432 -c "\copy tablename from 'data.csv' with DELIMITER ',';"
```

After giving my password I get the error "psql: FATAL:  could not write init file". I think this psql client may be version 9.2, is that something that matters? Or is this the wrong syntax for this type of transfer? Or, could it be related to having free trial size instances, which I believe have a 5 GB limit? I think I should be under that limit, but would it tell me if that were the problem? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to specify the absolute path to that `csv` file ex : - `\copy tablename from 'd:\myfiles\data.csv' with DELIMITER ',';`

Comment: It actually seems that it was a size issue. When I increased my RDS instance to 10 GB the error went away. There must be some amount of that 5 GB storage that goes something besides your uploaded files.

Comment: later comment: csv's seem to double in size when they are formatted as a sql table